# Can't install wordpress on localhost

Tags: wordpress, apache, openssl

Every time I'm trying to install wordpress from the address: `localhost/wordpress`

It's showing the "Parent Directory"

```
Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.11 Server at localhost Port 80.
```

[image]

Can anybody give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it looks like you have no files in your localhost/wordpress directory. You can follow the steps on this Codex page - https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress - to guide you through the install process. You first need to download and unzip the WordPress files from https://wordpress.org/download/ into your local folder. You also need to have PHP installed locally, set up a database and a user, and edit your wp-config.php file before you can access localhost/wordpress to run the install. It's all detailed in that Codex page.